MultiStyleLabel with Ellipsis
I'm not sure if I've found a Roku bug.  I'm using a MultiStyleLabel.  It extends LabelBase.  LabelBase supports an ellipsis for text that extends beyond a boundary.
I was using a standard Lablel object (which also extends LabelBase).  It was showing an ellipsis correctly for longer text.  I then switched to using a MultiStyleLabel and it no longer shows an ellipsis for the same text.  I have all of the proper component settings and did not change any during the conversion to MultiStyleLabel.
I tried extending MultiStyleLabel in the hopes of finding a workaround, but, I've had no success.
Has anyone encountered this and come up with a workaround?

There is no issue with MultiStyleLabel. Couple of fields should be checked whether set correctly--

wrap should be false
width should be defined
text length should be greater then width in pixels

As you can see in image, it's ellipsis as expected--

Please share the code snippet for better help.

There is a caveat to this answer. 'MaxLines' is ignored.  Using a "Label" with 'MaxLines' set to 2 and 'Wrap' set to "true", I was able to display an ellipsis.  Using a "MultiStyleLabel", it seems that it only supports one line of text.

More than one lines are possible with "MultiStyleLabel" but need to be tweaked little bit. Using "height" field instead of "MaxLines" dothe job. Though I agree that it should work with "MaxLines".
